# Javascript Voronoi points from polygons

Tags: javascript, polygon, voronoi, delaunay

I'm using [R. Hill's Voronoi implementation](https://github.com/gorhill/Javascript-Voronoi) to create polygons using an array of points:

```
sites=[{x:23, y:33},  {...}]
```

and also using an array with the canvas size:

```
box = {xl: 0, xr: 800, yt: 0, yb: 600}
```

Vornoi is generated with:

```
var diagram = voronoi.compute(sites, bbox);
```

The returned 'diagram' variable is a Javascript object with the following properties:

```
diagram.edges, diagram.cells, diagram.vertices
```

The object diagram.cells contains multiple cells each with 4 half-edges. Each half-edge has a lSite, rSite, va and vb objects containing x and y values.

However I am interested in obtaining an array of points (x,y) that form each polygon in the voronoi diagram and I have no idea how to do it.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Would that not be inside of the `diagram.cells` as you described? Can you give an exact sample of the data structure inside of `diagram`?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. You can see the exact content of a cell here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/93tjw0s5/)

Answer (score 0):

Found it: the method `getStartpoint()` can be applied to all the `halfedges` objects from within a `cell` object to obtain an array of points that form the polygon:
For example for cell 0:

```
var cellpoints=[];
for(e=0; e<diagram.cells[0].halfedges.length; e++){
    cellpoints.push([diagram.cells[0].halfedges[e].getStartpoint().x, diagram.cells[0].halfedges[e].getStartpoint().y])
}
```